# Filter by game mode in SingStar?

Tags: ps3, singstar

In *SingStar*, is there any way to filter the song listings when choosing a song, so only songs with dance or guitar gameplay are shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found a way and have been asking around the forums and blogs but nobody has found a way. I guess for now it is not possible.